# How does throws work at Java?

Tags: java, throws

I have been using catch and now I have to use throw. 
This is what I 've been given and I can't figure out what's missing so that it will work.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

     Exception_Tester et = new Exception_Tester();   

     int x1;
     int x2;

     x1=5;
     x2=0;


     et.printResults(x1,x2);


    }
    static void printResults(int a, int b) throws ArithmeticException  {

     System.out.println("Add: "+(a+b));
     System.out.println("Sub: "+(a-b));
     System.out.println("Mul: "+(a*b));
     System.out.println("Div: "+(a/b));


    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this article - How to throw exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) could help you.

Comment: In what way does it not work currently?

Comment: Please post the complete source code. Exception_Tester ist not defined and if the class of the main method is Exception_Tester then et.printResults(x1,x2) should be called in a static way -> Exception_Tester.printResults(x1,x2)

Comment: Before performing the division, evaluate if `b` is zero. If it is, throw a new `ArithmeticException` since you should not perform division by 0.

Answer (score 0):

try surrounding the (a/b) in a try statement.
then, in the catch, just throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your printResults method declares that it maight throw an exception of a type ArithmeticException. In order for that to happen something needs to go wrong inside the method, for instance if your b param would be zero an exception would be thrown. If you want to throw exception explicitly you need to use throw statement like this in your method

```
throw new ArithmeticException();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you catch an exception. Your code must throw an exception first. Sometimes there are runtime exceptions, which code itself throws. But sometimes you need a custom Exception to be thrown when some condition gets `true`. For that you use this `throw` keyword and throw an exception for your code to Catch it.

Here is a sample

```
public Object pop() {
    Object obj;

    if (size == 0) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }

    obj = objectAt(size - 1);
    setObjectAt(size - 1, null);
    size--;
    return obj;
}
```

It would throw the Exception customly and then you can catch it.

Although if the stack is zero. It might not throw that exception. So you yourself make the code throw that exception for yourself and then handle it somewhere. For that you'll use `try { } catch { }`.

For more on that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a custome exception class and throw the exception from wherever you think it can occur.

```
 public class MyException extends Exception {
      public MyException(String message) {
      super(message);
     }
 }
```

For instance in the division operation in your method. You can use it like..

```
  static void printResults(int a, int b){

     if(b == 0 ) {
    throw new MyException("Division by Zero"); 
     } else {
     System.out.println("Div: "+(a/b));
     }


    }
```